# VBA Excel: Find row in which more than 5 columns are being used

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a program that will compile multiple excel workbooks into one and plot the data. One problem I have run into is that the rows prior to the actual data varies and I want the code to be able to find the starting point by itself. On top of that, I would like it to use a range that starts from that row and continues all of the way down the spreadsheet until data ceases. [Data File Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qg8qV.png)

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub runHPO_Click()
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim FileName As String
Dim WorkBk As Workbook
Dim SourceRange As range
Dim DestRange As range
Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim cht As Chart

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Test specific section - directory, chart title
FolderPath = "I:\SHARED\Marshall Test Compiler\Performance Tests\3.2.1.7 HPO\"
FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.*")
ThisWorkbook.Charts.Add.Name = "HPO"
Set cht = ActiveChart
With cht
    .ChartType = xlXYScatterLinesNoMarkers
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = "3.2.1.7 Hot Pump Out"
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = "Time [min:sec]"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Fan Speed [rpm]"
End With

Do While FileName <> ""
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)).Name = FileName
    Set DataSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set WorkBk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
    Set SourceRange = WorkBk.Worksheets(1).range("A1:Z2045")
    Set DestRange = DataSheet.range("A1:Z2045")
    DestRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    'Change legend name to serial number
    Dim LName As String
    LName = DataSheet.range("A14").Characters(8, 9).Text

    'Add plotting
    Dim profTime As range
    Dim profInSpeed As range
    Dim profSpDemand As range
    Dim profLoLimit
    Dim xrange As range
    Dim fsrange As range
    Dim pwmrange As range
    Dim btrange As range
    Dim sdrange As range

    Set profTime = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").range("H4:H13")
    Set profInSpeed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").range("I4:I13")
    Set profSpDemand = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").range("J4:J13")
    Set profUpLimit = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Profiles").range("K4:K13")
    Set xrange = DataSheet.range("A797:A2045")
    Set fsrange = DataSheet.range("D797:D2045")
    Set pwmrange = DataSheet.range("J797:J2045")
    Set btrange = DataSheet.range("F797:F2045")
    Set sdrange = DataSheet.range("K797:K2045")

    xrange.NumberFormat = "mm:ss"
    profTime.NumberFormat = "mm:ss"

    'Profile
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Input Speed"
        .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
        .Values = profInSpeed
        .XValues = profTime
    End With
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Speed Demand"
        .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
        .Values = profSpDemand
        .XValues = profTime
    End With
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = "Fan Speed Upper Limit"
        .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
        .Values = profUpLimit
        .XValues = profTime
    End With

    'Fan Speed
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = LName & " Fan Speed"
        .AxisGroup = xlPrimary
        .Values = fsrange
        .XValues = xrange
    End With

    'PWM
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = LName & " PWM"
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .Values = pwmrange
        .XValues = xrange
    End With

    'Box Temp
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = LName & " Box Temp"
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .Values = btrange
        .XValues = xrange
    End With

    'Speed Demand
    With cht.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .Name = LName & " Speed Demand"
        .AxisGroup = xlSecondary
        .Values = sdrange
        .XValues = xrange
    End With

    WorkBk.Close savechanges:=False
    FileName = Dir()
Loop

With cht
    .HasAxis(xlValue, xlSecondary) = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Select
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).AxisTitle.Text = "PWM [%] / Box Temp [degC]"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).MaximumScale = 2400
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MaximumScale = 120
    .Axes(xlValue, xlSecondary).MinimumScale = -800
    .SeriesCollection(1).Delete
End With
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Compiler").Select
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! In general, splitting up your question into smaller, discrete questions about "how do I do..." is much easier for someone like me to help you. "I want the code to be able to find the starting point by itself." --- Lets talk about this problem. Have you heard of ```xlUp``` and ```xlDown```? What about using ```Cells(i,j)``` ? Google those and see where it might help!

Comment: Thank you, I will keep that in mind! I have done quite a bit of googling and tried a couple of variations with those, mostly including `.find`, but I couldn't seem to get it to work. I believe the exact code I used was `rowStart = DataSheet.Columns("K").Find(what:="*", After:=Cells("K1"), LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlNext)` and `fRow = rowStart.row`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, your data is obstructed by a lot of header information on the far left.  If this is always the case, you can select a column that will never have data in front of it and find the first row by using:

`FirstRow = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(1, 20).end(xlDown).Row`

(This assumes that column 20 is clear of all header data).  You can find the last row of contiguous data by using:

`LastRow = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(FirstRow, 20).end(xlDown).Row`

The last column:

`LastColumn = Sheets("Your Sheet Name").Cells(FirstRow, Columns.Count).end(xltoLeft).Column`

If it is not the case that there is an unobstructed column, I recommend you use the `.Find` function to find a unique number or alpha format.